# В предложении с обобщающим словом ставится двоеточие или тире?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

*В дальнем углу монастырского двора от стены к стене были протянуты веревки с развешанным для сушки стираным бельем ( ) рубашки с тяжелыми, набрякшими рукавами, скатерти персикового цвета, кривые, плохо выжатые простыни.*

Какой знак поставить на месте пропуска? Тире или же двоеточие? Почему именно? И как определить наверняка какой знак ставить при пояснении( а именно, то есть)?

Answer (score 3):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

**В дальнем углу монастырского двора от стены к стене были протянуты веревки с развешанным для сушки стираным бельем –  рубашки с тяжелыми, набрякшими рукавами; скатерти персикового цвета; кривые, плохо выжатые простыни.**

Пояснение

1) Постановка тире связана с **разным падежом** обобщающего слова и однородных членов, в этом случае ряд можно представить как присоединительную конструкцию.

2) Постановка точки с запятой связана с **наличием собственных знаков препинания** у однородных членов.

Answer (score 1):

Это однородные члены предложения с обобщающим словом. В подобных примерах обычно ставится двоеточие. Хотя и тире уже не считается ошибкой.

Вот правило.

**Если обобщающее слово предшествует ряду однородных членов, то после обобщающего слова ставится двоеточие:**

> Рыбак-подледник бывает **разный:** рыбак-пенсионер, рыбак — рабочий и служащий, рыбак-военный, рыбак-министр, так сказать, государственный деятель, рыбак-интеллигент (Сол.); В этом рассказе вы найдете почти всё, о чем я упоминал **выше:** сухие дубовые листья, седого астронома, гул канонады, Сервантеса, людей, непоколебимо верящих в победу гуманизма, горную овчарку, ночной полет и многое другое (Пауст.).

**Примечание. Допустимо используемое в современной практике печати при всех позициях обобщающих слов употребление тире, в том числе — перед перечислением (на месте традиционного двоеточия):**

> В новом цехе организуется массовое производство изделий для машиностроения — втулок, стаканов, зубчатых сеток (газ.); Хороших байдарочников было всего трое — Игорь, Шуляев, Коля Корякин и, разумеется, сам Андрей Михайлович (Тендр.);

[См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113)

Answer (score 0):

Это Пастернак. [Доктор Живаго](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=CPF9CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%D0%92%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=wLDOVsw1Go&sig=Z9q0czMZyMo1AKhUl5BigNYT5MY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-6qPd0MLVAhXEBsAKHcdOBwEQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false).

**В дальнем углу монастырского двора от стены к стене были протянуты веревки с развешанным для сушки стираным бельем – рубашки с тяжелыми, набрякшими рукавами, скатерти персикового цвета, кривые, плохо выжатые простыни.**

Почему тире? Ответ дала Arina: Постановка тире связана с разным падежом обобщающего слова и однородных членов, в этом случае ряд можно представить как присоединительную конструкцию.

P.S. С классиками не спорят, но, как говорится, "если бы редактором был я", то потребовал бы поставить однородные члены в "правильном" падеже.

Answer (score 0):

В дальнем углу монастырского двора от стены к стене были протянуты веревки с развешанным для сушки стираным бельем – рубашкАМИ с тяжелыми, набрякшими рукавами, скатертЯМИ персикового цвета, кривыМИ, плохо выжатыМИ простынЯМИ.

Comment: По сути, не является ответом на вопрос.